# Cannot start phpMyAdmin with Amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, amazon-rds

I have started an EC2 instance in Amazon and a mySQL RDS.
I am trying to install phpMyAdmin without success..
I have downloaded and extracted all files of phpMyAdmin to `/var/www/html/phpMyAdmin`, changed the **config.inc.php** to:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '[myDB].[randomstring].us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = TRUE;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '?????';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '??????';
```

And when I try to enter: the phpMyAdmin folder I get the following error:

> "The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP
>   configuration."

Answer (score 1):

for amazon add this before the command: sudo

so it looks like this:

> sudo yum install php-mbstring